# Calling methods - Not quite understand parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I'm trying to call a method, selectionSort, where I've set a parameter to be the array I'm sorting. I created an array 'A', then cloned it as 'B' so that I can keep the original.

When I try to call selectionSort(B), it won't sort B. If I call selectionSort(A), it works perfectly.

Here's the method code:

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] A){
    int location, position, check;
    for (location = A.length - 1; location > 0; location--){
        check = 0;
        for (position = 0; position <= location; position++){
            if (A[position] < A[check]){
                check = position;
            }//end if
            swap(A, check, location);
        }//end for
    }//end for
}//end method
```

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example.

Comment: Please define "won't sort". Compilation error? Incorrect results? Runtime exception?

Comment: to iterate over all elements, the terminating condition of your outer loop needs to be `location >= 0` (ie including 0)